# How do you view your database in Replit (Flask)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, replit

I made a database on Replit. I'm using Flask and SQLAlchemy. I was wondering whether anyone knows how I can see my database (e.g. on the Console log) because I think I've added the same new user 2 times.

Comment: There's no GUI interface. You'd access it programmatically or by `curl` as described in [the docs](https://docs.replit.com/hosting/databases/replit-database#where-can-i-find-my-database).

Answer (score 0):

**There is no GUI interface for Replit DB**

Since Replit DB is treated similarly to a Python dictionary, you should be able to just print the database like so:

```py
# importing database
from replit import db

# assigning some data so that it actually prints something out
db["hello"] = "hello, world!"

# printing the db
print(db)
```

The result should be the following:

```
>>> {"hello":"hello, world!"}
```

Therefore, you can directly use `db` when displaying database data.

Like so:

```py
from flask import Flask
from replit import db

app = Flask(__name__)
db["my_num"] = 3

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return db
```

### References

[Replit DB docs](https://docs.replit.com/hosting/databases/replit-database)

[Flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/)

*If my answer is unclear, please let me know by commenting.*